# Get entire url with php?

Tags: php, url, query-string

What variables do I need to use to build the exact url in the browser?

e.g. `[protocol][domain][path][get params]`

so I want to be able to have a variable contain `http://example.com/folder/file.php?something=value`

But I do not know what `$_SERVER` variables I can use to build this string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'PHP_SELF', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL', 'QUERY_STRING' $_SERVER elements to get the full path.

to know all the available $_SERVER elements, check the following page

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 3):

```
function current_url() {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") {
        $current_url = "https://";
    } else {
        $current_url = "http://";
    }
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != "80") {
        $current_url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ":" . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    } else {
        $current_url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
    return $current_url;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/get_current_page_url.php worked for me at least.